# Reference to QML Singleton Class Instance?

Tags: qt, qml, singleton, qtquick2

I have created a class called LoginService.
I registered it to QT QML file by using qmlRegisterSingletonType, now the problem is I can't get the loginservice instance which instantiated by QML. My current c++ code is:

```
static QObject *qmlInstance(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) {
    Q_UNUSED(engine);
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine);

    LoginService::m_pThis = new LoginService;
    return m_pThis;
}

qmlRegisterSingletonType<LoginService>("com.test.LoginService", 1, 0, "LoginService", &LoginService::qmlInstance);
```

Comment: I have another class called MainWindow, the MainWindow class have a member variable (LoginService *), I want to make this member point to the instance that QML generated. And then I can connect signals between LoginService and MainWindow in MainWindow's constructor function

Answer (score 6):

If you want to access the singleton from C++, create a method that returns an instance other than `qmlInstance`:

**loginservice.h**

```
#ifndef LOGINSERVICE_H
#define LOGINSERVICE_H

#include <QObject>

class QQmlEngine;
class QJSEngine;

class LoginService : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
public:
    static LoginService *instance();
    static QObject *qmlInstance(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine);

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);
    Q_SIGNAL void nameChanged();

private:
    explicit LoginService(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    static LoginService* m_pThis;
    QString mName;
};

#endif // LOGINSERVICE_H
```

**loginservice.cpp**

```
#include "loginservice.h"

#include <QQmlEngine>

LoginService* LoginService::m_pThis = nullptr;
LoginService::LoginService(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QString LoginService::name() const
{
    return mName;
}

void LoginService::setName(const QString &name)
{
    if(mName == name)
        return;
    mName = name;
    Q_EMIT nameChanged();
}

LoginService *LoginService::instance()
{
    if (m_pThis == nullptr) // avoid creation of new instances
        m_pThis = new LoginService;
    return m_pThis;
}

QObject *LoginService::qmlInstance(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) {
    Q_UNUSED(engine);
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine);
    // C++ and QML instance they are the same instance
    return LoginService::instance();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "loginservice.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterSingletonType<LoginService>("com.test.LoginService", 1, 0, "LoginService", &LoginService::qmlInstance);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    // get instance in C++
    LoginService *service = LoginService::instance();

    qDebug()<<service->name();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import com.test.LoginService 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

   Component.onCompleted: LoginService.name = "testing"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to get the same instance which generated by QML, not created by using c++ new operator, because in this case, it will generate two different LoginService

Comment: @Zain No, it is the same, if you notice in `qmlInstance` I use `LoginService::instance()`, and in `LoginService::instance()` only creates the instance if it does not exist, with my code there could never be 2 instances.

Comment: @Zain 
By definition a singleton should only have one instance, so it is the duty of the programmer to avoid creating new ones, and in your case it seems that you have not done so, in my solution if I avoid it because if the instance is null it creates, if it is not null, the same instance is returned, so I guarantee the uniqueness of the instance.

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. Now it works as expected! Thanks.